# Why tests fail on framework, but work on executable?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, arm64

While maintaining the old project I found interesting quirk, that poked my curiosity. I have framework that has some tests with it. Since this was written in 2013, the developer there added flag for `excluded architectures: Any iOS Simulator SDK arm64`. This meant if I wanted to run tests I needed to switch to Rosseta if I wanted to run them on my M1 Mac. On Intel Macs it run natively. If I did not use Rosseta, tests would fail to run, I would get linking error. So far so good.

Here is interesting part. But if I change my framework to be an app, and try to run same tests, it will not fail. It will run tests even if I don't select Rosseta simulator on my M1 mac. For all intents and purposes this should fail.

I will attach small project that is PoC of this -> https://github.com/MegaManX32/TestX86_64. One target is app (executable) and the other is framework.

So my question is, what is the difference, what is happening under the hood, and how can I make tests for framework work without switching to Rosseta simualtor?

Comment: Interesting, both the framework and the app can run on a arm64 simulator on my m1 mac.

Comment: did you try to run tests for the framwork, without invoking rosseta?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but I would be curious about the state of your derived data between the two attempts to build. Neither test builds would clean your build folder and I would suspect that if you had proper derived data from running the application on simulator with the target as an app properly, then running tests with the same app target would pick up the same data without needing to recompile everything.

I have found that a fairly large amount of derived is cached and reused until the build folder is cleaned and package caches are removed and sometimes it is enough that when you clear derived data, you build will no longer run as it does not have the cached data it was using. I'd be interested if running your tests of the framework vs the app with completed cleared derived data yields the same results.

Comment: I tried all obvious things, even the one that you mention with derived data. If you want you can clone POC (just few empty classes), that illustrates this scenario well.